# jQuery does not submit the form after modification

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML form:

```
<form action="../start_timer" class="start_timer" id="447" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="shift_id" value="447">
<input type="hidden" name="latitude" class="latitude">
<input type="hidden" name="longitude" class="longitude">
<input type="submit" value="Start">
</form>
```

and the following jQuery to handle the form submition:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( "form.start_timer, .form.end_timer" ).submit(function(e) {   
            if( $(this).children( ".latitude" ).val().length === 0 || $(this).children( ".longitude" ).val().length === 0 ){
                e.preventDefault();
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation,{timeout:10000});
                submits=0;
                $( ".longitude" ).change(function(e) {
                    if (submits==0) {
                    $(this).submit();
                    }
                    submits++;
                });
            }else if( $(this).children( ".latitude" ).val().length !== 0 && $(this).children( ".longitude" ).val().length !== 0 ){

                return true;

            }
        });
    });
```

Here is `foundLocation` fuction which fills in the hidden fields:

```
function foundLocation( position ){ 

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;

        if ($( ".latitude" ).val( lat )!="lat") {
        $( ".latitude" ).val( lat ).trigger('change');
        }

        if ($( ".longitude" ).val( long )!="long") {
        $( ".longitude" ).val( long ).trigger('change');        
        }
}
```

What happens is that it stops in the `else if` case and does not really submit the form.

How can I actually submit it after the modification?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it getting inside the else if block?

Comment: Can you show what is doing the foundLocation, I'm assuming it's updating the hidden fields values, but I want to be sure, also the else if statement can be replaced with a simple else since latitude and longitude will have a value at that point.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. Updated the question with foundLocation function. It does set values to hidden fields and then the else if block is executed, but form is not submitted.

The else if block is used in case only one (long or lat) is going to be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the getCurrentPosition function is async, so you are triggering the form submit before the function has returned the values, the form submission should be something like this:

```
$( "form.start_timer, .form.end_timer" ).submit(function(e) {   
    var form = $(this);

    if( $(this).children( ".latitude" ).val().length === 0 || $(this).children( ".longitude" ).val().length === 0 ) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var geolocated = function(position) {
             foundLocation(position);
             form.submit();
         };
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocated, noLocation,{timeout:10000});
    } else {
            return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, on the first click the form is not being submited and ends in the if block and on the second click it ends in the second block, but does not submit either.

Comment: You can see it working on this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/p2wumnrL/), if you open the network tab, you can see that the form is actually submitting the post (int the fiddle it will be a 404). Note that you don't need to click again, it will automatically submit once you get the geolocation values.

Answer (score 0):

Your foundLocation function is wrong, so is your event attachment.

your foundLocation should be :

```
function foundLocation( position ){ 

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;

    $( ".latitude" ).val( lat );
    $( ".longitude" ).val( long ).trigger('change');        

}
```

And try attaching the submit event like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "form.start_timer, .form.end_timer" ).submit(function(e) {   
        var dat = $(this);
        if( $(this).children( ".latitude" ).val().length === 0 || $(this).children( ".longitude" ).val().length === 0 ){
            e.preventDefault();
            dat.on('change', '.longitude, .latitude', function(e) {
                if(dat.find('.latitude').val() != "" && dat.find('.longitude').val() != "") dat.submit();
            });
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation,{timeout:10000});

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I cannot get such callback to be run. How can I do this?

Comment: Note that i did not include the code above and below, I'll edit my answer with the full `.ready()` callback